# I am having an issue with stripe checkout redirecting to the stripe payment page once deployed with Netlify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, netlify

Hi I am trying to integrate stripe checkout into my webapp. Whenever I click on the "purchase button" which is supposed to redirect you to the stripe checkout page, I get this error VM97:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "I have a Node.js & express backend that is handling the api call to stripe

However, in the localhost environment, I go through the same flow it works perfectly fine just as its expected to. It will open up the checkout page with the customers cart. I only get that error previously stated when deployed.

This is the api endpoint to handle the response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMFZh.png)

This is a call to the api in order to redirect to stripe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sR1z.png)

I made a few changes to the await function. I was thinking maybe the response was failing before it made it to the final ".then". Reason because the error is saying uncaught in promise.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The fact it was working on local but failed on deployed environment hints that your deployed environment doesn't have the correct Stripe Secret key, therefore it errored (500) while processing, causing client unable to process the response.

You would want to debug deeper on your server log to see the detailed error, and also check on your [Stripe request log](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs).

Comment: Great thank you very much for the feedback! Im going to look into this right now and get back to you with the new findings :D

Comment: ShippingInfo.jsx:16 POST bearysoftorganic.com/create-checkout-session 404 ,VM66:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON So after I tried to make the call to the api on the checkout page this is the error that Im getting.

Comment: 404 means your server is not serving the endpoint. You will need to look at your server routing configuration